# Why did Superman let the bomb explode in Batman v Superman?

Tags: dc, superman, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

Something has bothered me about the scene from BvS where the bomb goes off during the Congressional hearing: why did Superman let it go off where it was?  I am not talking about his answer in the next scene where he tells Lois he did not want to see it or whatever he said.  Specifically, I am wondering why he did not do something when he perceived the bomb *starting* to explode.  My rationale for this would be that Supes can basically go the speed of light which means it follows that he needs to *perceive* things that fast (correct me if I am wrong).  An explosion is fast but not nearly as fast as his ability to see it starting to explode.  It seems he could have carried the wheelchair out of the building in the process.  Am I wrong in thinking this way?  Is there canon comic evidence of him being able to do this?

Comment: Another issue you're facing is that the Superman of the comics and the Superman of the DC Movie universe are different entities.

Comment: If you move the gun after the trigger had been pulled, it won't stop the bullet. Same principle.

Answer (score 7):

As you said in the following scene, he told Lois he couldn't see it. If the bomb has already ignited, then it's going to rip thru the case and containing that explosion wasn't really possible. If he had been that fast, maybe he might have gotten the case out during detonation, but this seemed to catch him completely unaware-as he was dealing with the current interrogation.

Answer (score 7):

The Superman in this movie series is not faster than an expanding explosion, and even if he were, there wouldn't be much he could do once it was already exploding.

It's not like the explosion is a ball of solid matter he can pick up and carry out of the building.

Maybe he could grab the wheelchair, but at that point the cat's already out of the bag, so to speak. There's already a shockwave and fireball propagating through the atmosphere in the court room.

Comment: Agreed but I swear it doesn't make any sense that he literally doesn't move AT ALL during the explosion. Zack Snyder really needs to stop directing these movies.

Comment: He is faster than a speeding Flash.